# Can't Get PHP cURL SSL To Work

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get PHP cURL to return the headers from https://www.google.com.  I'm doing this so that I can understand how to configure the PHP curl_setopt parameters to work correctly with SSL websites.  By "correctly" I mean that I want cURL to apply the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER parameter to validate a server's security certificate.

This is new ground for me.  I've got a hazy understanding of how this process works, but I can't get the following code to return the google.com headers:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "c:/wamp/www/certificates/googleCA.cer");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // HTTP request is 'HEAD only'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'https://www.google.com');
$headers=curl_exec($ch);

print_r($headers);

echo "Got to end!";

?>
```

I've followed the instructions at the following link to extract a copy of the google.com certificate from Windows using IE11:

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

The certificate extraction described by the above link seems to go fine.  I'm on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  I save the top-level certificate from IE11 as a 'Base-64 encoded x.509 (CER)' file to my 'c:\WAMP\www\certificates\' folder as 'googleCA.cer'.  I then set the CURLOPT_CAINFO parameter to 'c:/wamp/www/certificates/googleCA.cer'.  When I execute the PHP code, the google headers AREN'T returned with the CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER parameter is set to "1" (I know setting the CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER to "0" instructs cURL to not validate the server certificate, which does return the headers, but that is a totally insecure configuration which I don't want to use ).

This feels like a problem with the certificate I exported from Windows using IE11.  I also found this link that describes downloading the cacert.pem file from the cURL website:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

When I click on the link above I get the text of the caextract file presented in IE11.  I don't know what to do next.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks In Advance!! --

EDIT: Here is the content of the googleCA.cer file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Is [this](http://pastebin.com/Bq8pQFV6) anything like what you have googleCA.cer?  The first is the Google G2 Internet Authority, and the second is the root CA, GeoTrust's Global CA cert.

Comment: I've added the contents of the googleCA.cer to the original post.  The two certificates you mentioned are what I saw in the list of certificates in IE11.  I only extracted the GeoTrust Global CA certification.

Comment: That should work fine as well.  What does `var_dump($headers); echo curl_error($ch);` show?

Comment: bool(false)
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Try putting both certs in the file like in my pastebin above and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I've never done that before.  The only option I saw using IE11 was to create a PB7 file.  I did that and tried using an SSL file converter but that didn't work.  Can I use Notepad to merge the certs together?

Comment: The certs cURL/OpenSSL expect are typically PEM encoded and can be chained together.  The idea is that the file contains a concatenation of ALL trusted certificates, and when you connect to a site, it looks in that file for the CA, and if found, considers the site trusted.  If the CA certificate for the site you're connecting to is not any of the certs in the CA bundle (CAINFO), then it aborts the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'll investigate how to use IE11 to get the root certificate and all intermediate certificates into one PEM file.

Comment: They are linked from the first comment, here: http://pastebin.com/Bq8pQFV6  You can just grab that to try really quick.

Comment: Thank, drew010.  I downloaded your pastebin file as a .txt file, changed the extension to .pem, and tried it.  Same results - an SSL cert error.

Comment: It you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` to the script, can you confirm in the output you see something like: `* Connected to www.google.com (50.0.2.251) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /tmp/googlecerts.crt` ?  That indicates it is using that CA file.  I see that and then `SSL certificate verify ok.` when I use that.

Comment: I'm getting the `Warning: curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* in C:\WAMP\www\SuggestScraper\google_response_headers.php on line 20` when I run the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));` statement.  Suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that before, but perhaps a Windows incompatibility.  Instead of `php://output`, you can try a regular file which you'll have to inspect after the request, something like `C:/Windows/Temp/curl.txt` or some place PHP can write to.

Comment: That suggestion worked.  It finds the cert file but I get the following error: `successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: c:/wamp/www/certificates/non-Equifax_certs.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
* Closing connection #0`.  It's finding the certificate file - it doesn't like the certificates themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer to this problem is that the root certificate displayed for https://www.google.com in IE11, "GeoTrust Global CA," is cross-rooted to an older GeoTrust root certificate named "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority."**   When the "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate that displays as the root in the 3-certificate chain showing in my IE11 is used by my PHP script as the root certificate for  https://www.google.com my PHP script can't authenticate https://www.google.com's certificate **BECAUSETHE REAL ROOT CERTIFICATE FOR https://www.google.com ISN'T THE "GeoTrust Global CA" CERTIFICATE BUT THE GeoTrust "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" certificate.**  Once I figured this out, I used the "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" in my PHP .PEM file and I successfully validated the https://www.google.com certificate.

You can see how the cross-rooting takes place by doing the following (I used IE11 for this):

1. Open a **BLANK** https://www.google.com Web page
2. Click the padlock icon in the URL window, then click "View certificates."
3. The Certificates window for https://www.google.com appears.  Click the Certification Path tab.  The certificate chain of three certificates will be displayed.  The "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate shows as the root certificate - BUT THAT'S NOT TRUE.
4. Close the Certificate window.  In the "Run" box in the Start Menu (I'm using Windows 7) type "certmgr.msc" and click the "OK" button.  This will launch Windows' Certificate Manager.
5. Click the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" entry in the left pane, then click "Certificates."
6. In the right pane, locate the "GeoTrust Global CA" certiticate.  Double-click this entry to open it's certificate window.
7. Click the "Details" tab, then click the "Edit properties" button.  NOTE THAT "Server Authentication," "Client Authentication,"  "Code Signing," "Secure Email," and "Time Stamping" are selected.
8. Click the "Disable all purposes for this certificate" button.  THIS WILL DISABLE THIS CERTIFICATE FROM USE.  NOTE ON THE "General" TAB THAT THE EXPIRATION DATE FOR THIS CERTIFICATE IS 5/20/2022 AND THE "Issued to:" and "Issued by:" ITEMS ARE BOTH SIGNED "GeoTrust Global CA," INDICATING THAT THIS IS A ROOT CERTIFICATE. Click the "OK" button to return to the Windows Certificate Manager.  Minimize the Certificate Manager.
9. Move to your blank https://www.google.com Web page. **Refresh the page**, then view the certificates.  NOW YOU WILL SEE FOUR CERTIFICATES, INSTEAD OF THE THREE THAT WERE DISPLAYED IN SETP #3!!
10. WHAT HAPPENED?  Double-click the "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate.  Look at the expiration date on the "General" tab.  It's 8/20/2018, NOT THE 5/20/2022 displayed for the "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate in Step #3.  Also look at the "Issued to:" and "Issued by:" items - THEY ARE DIFFERENT.  The "Issued to:" is "GeoTrust Global CA" and the "Issued by" is "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority."  THIS IS A DIFFERENT "GeoTrust Global CA" CERTIFICATE THAT THE ONE DISPLAYED IN STEP #3!!  **This version of the "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate is cross-rooted to "Equifax Security Certificate Authority" as evidenced in the "Issued by:" item!!**
11. Double click the "GeoTrust" root certificate.  Notice that this is a self-signed root certificate issued by "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority."  **THIS IS THE REAL ROOT CERTIFICATE USED BY https://www.google.com!!**  When I copied this certificate into my PHP .PEM file and used it to validate https://www.google.com's certificate everything work perfectly!!
12. Go back to the Windows Certificate Manager and reverse the disablement you performed in Steps 5 - 8.  Click the "Enable only the following purposes" button and re-check the purposes listed in Step #7.  This will restore your "GeoTrust Global CA" certificate dated 5/20/2022 to functioning status.

There's a link on the GeoTrust Website that describes the "GeoTrust Global CA" cross-root certificate that appeared in Step #9.  You can download it as well.  However, for my application the cross-root certificate didn't validate https://www.google.com's certificate - I NEEDED TO USE THE "GeoTrust" ROOT CERTIFICATE BECAUSE IT IS THE ONLY ONE THAT WORKS TO VALIDATE https://www.google.com.  Here's the link:

https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=AR1426

You can also download the equivalent of the "GeoTrust" certificate from the GeoTrust Website.  It's listed as the "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" in the Resources > Root Certificates section of the Website.  Here's the link:

https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/

You can also find more details about the certificate chain for **any** Web page by visiting the following Symantec Web page:

https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com

I hope this helps you PHP developers who need to validate an HTTPS connection with Google.com. DREW010 - Thanks for hanging with me through this!  I appreciate your help.