# "cURL error 60: SSL certificate pr0blem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, octobercms

I am configuring google analytics on October CMS. I have pointed to .PEM file on October CMS. cURL is returning an error, *"cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"*.

I followed all the steps mentioned in the section on troubleshooting of the [RainLab Google Analytics Plugin](https://github.com/rainlab/googleanalytics-plugin). But I still see the same error.

I'm running PHP 5.6 on Windows 2012 with IIS 8 and the line of php.ini is:

Any idea what could be happening?

---

PHP info:

```
OpenSSL support enabled

OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

Directive Local Value Master Value 
openssl.cafile C:\Certificados\cacert.pem C:\Certificados\cacert.pem 
openssl.capath no value
```

EDITED: Added Image Capture.
[image]

And configuring...
[image]

php.ini configuration
[image]

Comment: They may have changed certs recently and it isn't in cURL's cacert.pem.  Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36227437/892493

Comment: What URL are you connecting to, and where is the package or link with the cacert.pem?

Comment: Sorry , but no URL , no package or link that I can configure. The .pem file path is defined by PHP.INI .

Comment: @AlfredSevero - Unfortunately, there's probably not much we can do to help you. Maybe you will have better luck at [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try https://github.com/OFFLINE-GmbH/oc-bootstrapper#troubleshooting

Comment: will try this tonight